# 'Cannot find file error' from SAP VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript, sap-gui

I'm running a script that extracts from SAP a number of N archives(based on a input file that contains the name of each file). The scripts reads the data for each file from a input txt file and writes the status after each run to an Excel file.

After each run the file is generated but before being saved it gives this
[error](https://unsee.cc/715ac380/).

> Windows cannot find 'filename.zip'. Make sure you typed the name correctly and then try again

I have disabled the Read Only option of the folder where I'm saving the report, I've run `sfc /scannow` in case I have any corrupted files in my system and I have also checked the Path variables in case any were missing but to no avail.

Here is the code

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If

Set filesysobj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set list = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set file = filesysobj.OpenTextFile("fullpath\to\input\file\.txt", 1)

' wb - workbook(the file), ws-worksheet(the first sheet of the excel file)
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("fullpath\to\excel\output\file")
objExcel.Visible = False
Set sheet = objWorkbook.sheets("Sheet1")

' Reading from the input file
nr = 0
Do until file.AtEndOfStream
    request = file.ReadLine
    list.Add nr, request
    nr = nr + 1
Loop
file.Close

' Indexes for the lines and rows in the excel file
i = 2 ' Second Row
j = 5 
For Each line in list.Items
On Error Resume Next
    session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "controlpanel\path"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[2]").press

    ' line - name from file
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtZQT1D-REQ").text = line
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtZQT1D-REQ").caretPosition = 9
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsREQUEST_OBJECTS/tabpREQUEST_OBJECTS_FC6/ssubREQUEST_OBJECTS_SCA:/SYMSOFT/CP_ZQTMS010_NEW:0917/cntlCONTAINER/shellcont/shell").currentCellColumn = "DATE"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsREQUEST_OBJECTS/tabpREQUEST_OBJECTS_FC6/ssubREQUEST_OBJECTS_SCA:/SYMSOFT/CP_ZQTMS010_NEW:0917/cntlCONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = "0"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsREQUEST_OBJECTS/tabpREQUEST_OBJECTS_FC6/ssubREQUEST_OBJECTS_SCA:/SYMSOFT/CP_ZQTMS010_NEW:0917/cntlCONTAINER/shellcont/shell").pressToolbarButton "ATT_DISP"

    ' define of the output path for the file & the filename
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").text = "fullpath\saving\folder"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").text = line & ".zip"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").setFocus
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").caretPosition = 26
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press

'  -------Writing the errors
' End If
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    sheet.Cells(i, j).Value = "Error " & Err.Description
    i = i + 1
Else
    sheet.Cells(i, j - 1) = line
    sheet.Cells(i, j) = "has been completed"
    i = i + 1
End If
next

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save 
objExcel.Quit
```

The archives are saved correctly but without clicking OK on the error the script won't get past 1 iteration nor it will save the archive.

Comment: Please don't post images of error messages. Put the actual message as text in the question.

Comment: One or your `request` from the input file contains nothing but whitespace. I would check to be sure the file exists before continuing, (or at least check if the request contains something else then whitespace)

Comment: @GeertBellekens Thank you for your reply, but the file exists, there aren't any other characters than needed.